# How do i add a foreign key constraint to a polymorphic column?

Tags: php, laravel

```
Schema::create('watchlists', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
    $table->morphs('media');
    $table->timestamps();
}
```

If a media gets deleted, I want the corresponding records in the watchlists table to delete too.

`morphs()` returns void so I can't chain more methods.

Comment: You can't put a foreign key constraint on a polymorphic column, which means you can't use `ON DELETE CASCADE` on it.

Answer (score -1):

To achieve a foreign key constraint on a polymorphic column in Laravel, you can use a combination of morphs() and manual foreign key constraints. However, it's worth noting that Laravel doesn't support foreign key constraints on morphed columns out-of-the-box. Therefore, you'll need to manage this manually.

Here's an example of how you can do this with rich comments:

```
Schema::create('watchlists', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    
    // Define a foreign key to the users table
    $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();

    // Define the morphed columns for media
    $table->string('media_type'); // This will store the type of the related model (e.g., 'App\Models\Image')
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('media_id'); // This will store the ID of the related model

    $table->timestamps();
});

// Define the foreign key constraint manually
Schema::table('watchlists', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreign(['media_id', 'media_type'])
          ->references(['id', 'type']) // Adjust this to match your media table's primary key and type column
          ->on('media_table_name') // Replace with the actual name of your media table
          ->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

Explanation

> 1. Create a watchlists table with its columns.
> 2. Define a foreign key constraint for the user_id column using Laravel's constrained() method.
> 3. Add two columns (media_type and media_id) to represent the polymorphic relationship. These columns will store the related model's
>    type and ID.

After creating the table, you manually define a foreign key constraint on the polymorphic columns. You'll need to adjust media_table_name, id, and type to match the actual column names in your media table.

Please replace the placeholders like media_table_name, id, and type with your actual column and table names.

Keep in mind that managing polymorphic relationships with foreign key constraints requires extra care, and you should thoroughly test your application to ensure that everything works as expected.